# Disable TLS requirement for Salesforce Out Bound Messages

Tags: community, configuration, workflowoutboundmessage, tls, disable

Is there a way in Salesforce to disable this required authentication for outbound messages? We are getting Error of  Server chose TLSv1.
Now the server we have is Running Frame Work of 4.7 which natively runs Protocol type TLS1.2 but Salesforce is refusing to connect, I even disabled the Protocol security from the remote sites still not able to receive outbound any workaround?

Comment: instead of https can you just provide `http://yoursite.com `?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Thanks for the comment,  I asked the project manager for that he said because the sensitive info is being passed around in between 2 sites we need the secure connection. I already have the http site working they want to use https

Comment: can you post error message, and which cert are you using. Is it from credible CA authority. Outbound messages support following. https://cs108.salesforce.com/cacerts.jsp